# Can't install winrun4j eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, winrun4j

I'm having issues installing the WinRun4J eclipse plugin. Eclipse finds the plugin just fine and begins the installation, but most of the way through the install eclipse stops at an error. The error is below. I've tried googling for a resolution to this error for the better part of 30 minutes, but I can't find anything that works. Aside from googling I've restarted eclipse multiple times and run it as administrator. No luck. How would I resolve this error?

[image: Error]

Here's my eclipse info:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the update site is invalid. It also looks like this software is no longer maintained. Your best bet is to download the eclipse plugin jar directly and place it into your `eclipse/dropins` folder.

You can download the [latest plugin jar here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winrun4j/files/winrun4j_eclipse/0.1.3/). Be careful, though, looks like this hasn't been touched in 6 years.